# How we can get payload data at the time of click tray when app is closed in Android push notification?

Tags: java, android, react-native, flurry, react-native-fcm

I m using React Native Flurry SDK (react-native-flurry-sdk)

[Flurry push React-native](https://github.com/flurry/react-native-flurry-sdk#api-reference)

[Flurry push Android Native](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/push/integration/android/)
It is working fine

```
// Optionally add a listener to receive messaging events, and handle the notification.
// Please call required Flurry.willHandleMessage(boolean) when received event types of
// MessageType.RECEIVED or MessageType.CLICKED as soon as possible to avoid delay.
Flurry.addMessagingListener((message) => {
  if (message.Type === Flurry.MessageType.RECEIVED) {
    Flurry.willHandleMessage(false);
  } else if (message.Type === Flurry.MessageType.CLICKED) {
    Flurry.willHandleMessage(false);
  }

  Flurry.printMessage(message);
});

// Message.Type: Flurry.MessageType = { RECEIVED,  CLICKED,
//                                      CANCELLED, REFRESH } (Android only)
// Message.Title:       message title
// Message.Body:        message body
// Message.Data:        message data (Map)
// Message.ClickAction: click action (Android only)
// Message.Token:       refreshed token
Flurry.addMessagingListener(callback: (message: { Type: string;
                  Title?: string; Body?: string; Data?: { [key: string]: string; }; ClickAction?: string;
                  Token?: string; }) => void);
Flurry.removeMessagingListener(callback: (message: { Type: string;
                  Title?: string; Body?: string; Data?: { [key: string]: string; }; ClickAction?: string;
                  Token?: string; }) => void);
Flurry.willHandleMessage(handled: boolean);
Flurry.printMessage(message: { Type: string;
                  Title?: string; Body?: string; Data?: { [key: string]: string; }; ClickAction?: string;
                  Token?: string; });
```

Problem is when app is closed but i got notification from tray while i m clicking the tray app is opened but

> i didn't get payload data in console(debug mode) or alert.

Can you give me a any logic solution or any document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean onNotificationClicked(final FlurryMessage flurryMessage) {
sEnableMessagingListener = true;
new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.i("tag", "This'll run 300 milliseconds later");
                Log.d("Click0012","ff11"+ "ggg"+ sReactApplicationContext + "ddd" + flurryMessage);

                Log.d("message001","ff"+flag +"999"+ sReactApplicationContext+"ff"+ sEnableMessagingListener);
                if (sEnableMessagingListener  && (sReactApplicationContext != null)) {
                    Log.d("Clicked002","ff"+flurryMessage);
                     sendEvent(EventType.NotificationClicked, flurryMessage, true);
                }
            }
        },
        900);



return false;
```

}